# How can i add options menu to fragment from NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation, android-optionsmenu

Hi i'm having a little bit of trouble, i'm trying to add options menu into my fragment (VoiceCoiSelectionFragment) i have this navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/communication_menu_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/commMenuFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/commMenuFragment"
        android:name="ca.stackoverflow.menu.comm_menu.CommMenuFragment"
        android:label="@string/comm_menu_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_comm_menu">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_commMenu_to_voiceCois"
                app:destination="@+id/voiceCoi" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/voiceCoi"
            android:name="ca.stackoverflow.VoiceCoiSelectionFragment"
            android:label="@string/voiceCoi"
            tools:layout="@layout/coi_panel" />
</navigation>
```

on the button click i have

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(CommMenuFragmentDirections.actionCommMenuToVoiceCois())
```

In my VoiceCoiSelectionFragment i try to add hasOptionsMenu to true than inflate it in

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull final Menu menu, @NonNull final MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.saving, menu);
    }
```

The onCreate of my activity contain

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(_viewBinding.menuAppBar, _navController, menuAppBarConfig);
        _viewBinding.menuAppBar.setNavigationIcon(ca.rheinmetall.argus.R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        _viewBinding.menuAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
```

but it doesn't work do i missing something ?

Comment: Are you calling [`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) in your Fragment's `onCreate()`?

Comment: yes, i'm calling it onCreate()

Comment: Can you include your activity code where you call `setSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: yep that was it i forgot to add this in my activity setSupportActionBar(_viewBinding.menuAppBar);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fragment menu APIs require two things:

1. That you have an ActionBar at the activity level via the correct theme or by using `setSupportActionBar()`
2. That you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your Fragment's `onCreate()`

Make sure you have done both things.